# Unable to run 32bit VM Guests on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, vmware, qemu, linux-kvm

I have an old 17" MacBook Pro that's too old for modern macOS with an intel i7-2720QM CPU.

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it, running Linux kernel 5.4.0-52-generic.

Try as I might I can't get guests to run in 32bit mode. I've tried both VMWare Workstation 16 Player, Virt Manager, and just raw qemu-system-i386 but no luck here.

My testing involves an old Windows ME physical disk, two OpenBSD ISOs (one 32bit, one 64bit), and a Ubuntu 08.04 ISO. Despite the VM being configured for Windows ME in both KVM and VMWare, only the 64bit OpenBSD VM boots.

In the case of the other operating systems in VMWare:

- Ubuntu will show "Operating System not found
- Windows ME shows "Operating System not found"

Virt Manager, most 32bit OSes show:

```
Booting from DVD/CD...
Boot failed: Could not read from CDROM (code 0004)
```

Could it be that security fixes for spectre, meltdown, and friends has limited this machine's ability to virtualize 32bit guests?

Update Nov 13:

Today, Ubuntu in Virt Manager is able to start and get far enough along to play the logon sound (so very much booting) while the same ISO in VMWare fails. This means it's not the bitness at play here.

VMWare is able to boot from floppy. Installed MS-DOS 6.22 but was unable to boot from hard disk. I'm able to boot Windows ME from a Windows 98 rescue floppy from WinWorld.

Comment: “Could it be that security fixes for spectre, meltdown, and friends has limited this machine's ability to virtualize 32bit guests?” - No

Comment: So what happens when you try to boot a 32-bit guest?

Comment: Part of the problem here turned out that Virt Manager took over ownership of the ISO files, giving the ownership specifically to libvirt-qemu:kvm which prevented VMWare from doing anything with them. It may be that my Windows ME ISO as ripped from the drive may be bad due to drive problems. I'm voting to close my own question here but the permissions may help others.